# Tikz setcounter not working

Tags: tikz-pgf, counters, foreach

I have tried to emulate other code using letters instead of numbers in the `foreach` in `tikz`, so here is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,automata, positioning}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[H]\centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth', auto,node distance=2.5cm]
        \foreach \a in {1,2,...,5} { 
            \setcounter{nodeCount}{\a}
            \ifthenelse{\a <= 2}{
                \draw (2*\a, 0) node[state, name = \Alph{nodeCount}] {$\Alph{nodeCount}$};
            }
            {
                \draw (2*\a - 6, 1) node[state, name = \Alph{nodeCount}] {$\Alph{nodeCount}$};
            }
            \edef\underNode{nodeCount}
            \addtocounter{nodeCount}{5}
            \node[state, above of = \Alph{\underNode}, name = \Alph{nodeCount}]{$\Alph{nodeCount}$};
        }
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I am trying to draw this:

[image]

How do I properly code it up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be the code you wanted to produce. First of all, you need

```
\newcounter{nodeCount}
```

Then you probably wanted to say

```
\edef\underNode{\Alph{nodeCount}}
```

You do not need the `ifthen` package here, `arrows` got superseded by `arrows.meta`, and you were loading but not using the positioning library, now it uses the correct syntax `above=of ...` instead of `above of=...`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,automata,positioning}
\usepackage{float}
\newcounter{nodeCount}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[>=Stealth, auto,node distance=2.5cm]
        \foreach \a in {1,2,...,5} { 
            \setcounter{nodeCount}{\a}
            \ifnum\a<3
             \draw (2*\a, 0) node[state, name = \Alph{nodeCount}] {$\Alph{nodeCount}$};
            \else               
             \draw (2*\a - 5, 1.5) node[state, name = \Alph{nodeCount}] {$\Alph{nodeCount}$};
            \fi
            \edef\underNode{\Alph{nodeCount}}
            \addtocounter{nodeCount}{5}
            \node[state, above=of \underNode, 
            name = \Alph{nodeCount}]{$\Alph{nodeCount}$};
        }
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This does not look really like the target output, which can be obtained very easily e.g. with a `matrix`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,matrix}
\newcounter{nodeCount}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[c/.style={state,execute at begin node={%
    $\stepcounter{nodeCount}%
    \Alph{nodeCount}$}}]
 \matrix[matrix of nodes,row sep=-6em,column sep=1em] (mat)
 {  & & |[c]| & &  |[c]|  & &  \\
  |[c]| & &  &|[c]| &   & & |[c]|  \\
    & & |[c]| & &  |[c]|  & &  \\
 & |[c]|  &  & |[c]|  &   &  |[c]| & \\
    };
 \path (mat-1-3.south)  (mat-4-2.north);  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh god, how could I leave out the `\newcounter`... also, why did you replace the `ifthenelse` with the `ifnum else fi` scope? I also edited my code to get the right positions of the upper nodes, by the way.

Comment: @Superman I had some interesting experience with `ifthen` in the past so I do not use it. If anything I'd use `xifthen` but I did not encounter a case in which I needed it on top of pgf.

Comment: I figured out why my `ifthenelse` failed; it didn't recognize the `<=` operator.

Comment: What does `\path (mat-1-3.south)  (mat-4-2.north); ` do?

Comment: @Superman I had some similar experiences, you really do not need it when you have pgf. BTW, with your updated code one does qualitatively reproduce the target output. I also added a matrix solution, in which `\path (mat-1-3.south) (mat-4-2.north);` corrects the bounding box, which is necessary because the `row sep` is negative.

Comment: So `(mat-1-3.south)` and `(mat-4-2.north)` depict the distances between top left and bottom left, and top right and bottom right, respectively? Also, out of curiosity, you set `row sep` negative to flip the order, right (bottom up instead of top down)?

Comment: Also, what does `c/.style = {something}` do?

Comment: @Superman Whenever you say `\path (<coordinate>);` the bounding box will be updated to include that point. And yes, I made the `row sep` negative because that way I do not have to type `A`, `B` and so on. I only need to fill in `|[c]|` and Ti*k*Z does the rest. `c` us a style that steps the counter and fills in the letter.

Comment: Do you mind making some notes on where `(mat-1-3.south)` and `(mat-4-2.south)` are? Like, draw arrows and/or make comments

Comment: So you said that you made `row sep` negative so that you don't have to type the letters one by one. Wouldn't it be the same if you made `row sep` positive, but the order of the letters will go downward instead of upward (or upside down)?

Comment: Finally, in this block of code, `[c/.style={state,execute at begin node={%
    $\stepcounter{nodeCount}%
    \Alph{nodeCount}$}}]`, `execute at begin node` is obvious, but where can I find other examples using `{something.style} = {some command}`? I am trying to familiarize myself with that process in case I have to do something similar or have to make a command in the brackets.

Comment: @Superman You can do `\draw[<->] (mat-1-3.south)  (mat-4-2.north);` to see where these coordinates are. And it is the `execute at begin node` which allows us to do that (well, not quite, there are plenty alternatives). You can always say something like `magic/.code={...}`, see section **88.1.2 Quick Guide to Using the Key Mechanism** of pgfmanual v3.1.5,

Comment: I actually used `\path (mat-1-3.south) edge (mat-4-2.north);` to actually find out where they are. Also, I was experimenting with placing the `\path` command and removing it, from what I saw, putting the `\path` command shifts the `tikzpicture` down.

Comment: @Superman If you remove it, the bounding box will be incorrect.

Comment: Hmmmmm I may need to see a visual of it to better understand what's going on. Do you know how to make the bounding box visible to the user?

Comment: @Superman `\draw (current bounding box.south west) rectangle  (current bounding box.north east);` before `\end{tikzpicture}` or with `show background rectangle` from the `backgrounds` library, see p. 577 of pgfmanual v3.1.5.

Comment: Thank you so much! The outputs are as desired, but I want to make sure that I understand the syntax and commands before I use them (otherwise I would be blindly using them and run into more problems if I try to apply them in different situations).

Comment: @Superman That's a good attitude. Be aware, though, that if you ask three users you will get five different opinions. For instance, not everyone will agree with my judgement of `ifthen`, say.

Comment: I will keep those differences in opinions in mind. For me, I just want to know how the mechanisms work in the end, as `LaTeX` is powerful yet enigmatic itself, hence underrated.